# Create custom stylesheet through javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was putting together a react-native app and noticed one glaring annoyance. Every time I wanted to use a theme when creating a stylesheet, I had to import the theme from an external file to use it.

Something like this

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { theme } from 'path-to-theme/theme.js'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: theme.background
    }
})
```

Coming from a React background, what I was wanting to do is get the theme provided to the constructor of sorts, so I don't have to do an import every time. Kind of like [material-ui does it](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#material-ui-39-s-styling-solution)

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'custom-stylesheet-path/stylesheet.js'

const styles = StyleSheet.create(theme => {
    container: {
        backgroundColor: theme.background
    }
})
```

But I'm not sure how to go about the implementation. Especially providing the theme to the stylesheet constructor. Anybody got any experience with this? Even just a starting point

Comment: Create a custom theme using `Stylesheet` , and import and merge the style objects wherever you want to use it using spread operator.

Comment: Pass theme with context,but in this way,'StyleSheets.create' will be called in instance,

Answer (score -2):

[NativeBase](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/ThemeVariables.html) is able to implement themes in react native. The way that it does it, is to create the standard set of react native components and then require that you import those elements from `native-base` rather than `react-native`.

Example:

```
import { Label } from 'native-base'
```

Rather than:

```
import { Text } from 'react-native'
```

Comment: I'm happy to make updates to my answer if it didn't help, but if it gets marked down and no one comments why, then I'm left to just guess.